# Total charge of hollow sphere with asymmetric charge density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge

We have  a sphere with outer radius B and inner radius A such that B is a solid sphere with a sphere of radius A removed. The charge density throughout this spherical volume between A and B is $1/|(r-r_0)|$. where $r_0$ is a point on the $z$ axis and $r$ is just a vector from the origin to a point in this volume.

Apparently, the value we get for this total charge varies depending on whether r nought is less than a, between a and b, or greater than b. I cannot see why this is the case.

My approach: $\nabla\cdot E=4\pi\rho$, where $rho$ is the charge density.

I found an $E$ that satisfies this relation.
Then using divergence theorem, I should be able to get an answer just by calculating the flux
Why? Because $\int F\cdot ds=\int \nabla\cdot E dV= \int4\pi\rho dV=4\pi Q$ where $Q$ is the total charge.

Problem is, my approach doesn't provide a distinction between these three cases of r nought varying. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'd like to understand why we have three different cases.

Comment: What three cases do you mean? Can you write explicitly what electric fields you've found?

Comment: Apparently the value of charge would vary according to whether the r nought vector is less than a, between a and b, or greater than b. (given in the question) I don't understand why this should be the case.